# How to split multiple line output to arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe, substitution

Let the output of a program to be a multiple line text:

```bash
$: some_program 
↓
line 1
line 2
```

Now how to use the output so each line is passed as a single argument?

```bash
$: count_arguments $(some_program)
↓
4
```

won't work because it split by new lines and spaces.

```bash
count_arguments "$(some_program)"
↓
1
```

won't work either.

With an intermediary step could the output be `read` into an array and then use the array as `"${arr[@]}"`

But I am looking for a one line solution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With Bashv4+, `mapfile` is one solution.

```
mapfile -t output < <(some_command); your_command "${output[@]}"
```

or

```
echo "${#output[*]}"
```

Counting the output of some_command, just use `wc`

```
some_command | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the newlines to NULL characters, and use `xargs -0` (the `-0` tells it to use NULL as a delimiter, instead of whitespace):

```
some_program | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 count_arguments
```

There is one possible caveat, though: if `xargs` thinks there are too many lines (arguments) or they're too big, it'll split them into reasonable-sized groups and run the utility separately on each group. OTOH if `xargs` thinks that, it's probably right any any method that *didn't* split them would just straight-up fail.